# javascript constructor syntax

Tags: javascript, constructor

I want to create a simple application for managing contacts. I want to be able to add new contacts and delete contacts. So I'm thinking the best approach is to create a contacts constructor so as to be able to create contacts objects with it. I'm planing to use set and get methods with this constructor.

How do I create a contacts constructor with these value in it.

The contact information should be represented as JSON, for example:

```
{
  "id": "0001",
  "first_name": "Charles",
  "last_name": "Bronson",
  "year_of_birth": 1921,
  "email": "charles@bronson.com",
  "image_url": "http://image.toutlecine.com/photos/b/r/o/bronson-charles-01-g.jpg",
  "addresses": {
    "address": [
      { "id": "1001", "street_name": "Storgata", "city": "Åhus" },
      { "id": "1003", "street_name": "Lillgata", "city": "Åhus" },
    ]
  },
  "phones": [
    { "id": "5001", "type": "mobile", "number": "070112233" },
    { "id": "5002", "type": "home", "number": "046445566" 
  ]
}
```

is this a correct way to create a constructor of this sort?

```
function contacts() {
  this.id = id;
  this.first_name = first_name;
  this.last_name    = last_name;
  this.year_of_birth = year_of_birth;
  this.email = email;
  this.image_url = image_url;
  this.adressess = adress["id", "street_name", "city"];
  this.phones = phone["id", "type", "number"];
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried "this.addresses = addresses;"?

Comment: Is there going to be some methods in the Contact function ?

BTW : for constructor functions, you should give them a name with an uppercase on the first letter, and since it is not a collection but a single contact, it should not be named with an 's'.

Comment: `adress["id", "street_name", "city"];` is same `adress["city"];`, what is `adress`, where you get value for filling field inside constructor? anyway [JSON.Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can return you object that you want from this json

Comment: Is there going to be some methods in the Contact function ? I don't think so. I want to make a simple application for managing contacts. So I need to be able to add, list and remove contacts.

Comment: can you provide code sample how you want use it?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of address objects within an `addresses` object:

`addresses.address[0].id` is the way to get the id of the first address object in that array.

`addresses.address[1].id` would get the id of the second address object

and so on...